# Is there any difference between the result for dual and primal of SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

There are many variants of types of solver in [liblinear](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/). But, I am kind of wondering whether there will be any difference for primal and dual for L2-loss. They suppose to be different forms of the optimization. Will they give different results?

```
-s type : set type of solver (default 1)
  for multi-class classification
   0 -- L2-regularized logistic regression (primal)
   1 -- L2-regularized L2-loss support vector classification (dual)
   2 -- L2-regularized L2-loss support vector classification (primal)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At worst, the resulting models should still be approximately equal since this is a convex optimization problem.

Their paper at JMLR<sup>[1](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/liblinear.pdf)</sup> mentions *"LIBLINEAR implements a trust  region Newton method"* for L2-SVM.

Reading the guide<sup>[2](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf)</sup>, in Apendix C.3 the following problem is discussed:

> **C.3**    *Number of instances ≫ number of features*
>
> As the number of features is small, one often maps data to higher
>   dimensional spaces (i.e., using  nonlinear  kernels). However,  if 
>   you really  would  like  to  use  the  linear kernel, you may use
>   LIBLINEAR with the option -s 2. When the number of features is small,
>   it is often faster than the default -s 1. Consider the data
>   [http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary/covtype.libsvm.binary.scale.bz2].
>   The number of instances 581,012 is much larger than the number of
>   features 54. We run LIBLINEAR with -s 1 (default) and -s 2.
>
> \$ time liblinear-1.21/train -c 4 -v 5 -s 2
>   covtype.libsvm.binary.scale 
> Cross Validation Accuracy = 75.67%
>   
> 67.224s
>
> \$ time liblinear-1.21/train -c 4 -v 5 -s 1
>   covtype.libsvm.binary.scale 
> Cross Validation Accuracy = 75.6711%
>   
> 452.736s
>
> Clearly, using -s 2 leads to shorter training time.

See the cross validation accuracy is approximately the same. So it's mostly a matter of training time.

---

[<sub>[1] Fan, Rong-En, et al. "LIBLINEAR: A library for large linear classification." Journal of machine learning research 9.Aug (2008): 1871-1874</sub>.](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/liblinear.pdf)

[<sub>[2] Hsu, Chih-Wei, Chih-Chung Chang, and Chih-Jen Lin. "A practical guide to support vector classification"(http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf." (2003).</sub>](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf)